# Wordpress, not showing full width

Tags: css, wordpress

Kept failing to make the content page full width. How do you search where in the CSS to edit for the Wordpress content to display full width?

Tried going to stylesheet.css and searched everywhere to make "max-width: 100%;", but still no luck, perhaps I'm changing the wrong class?

Example link: https://ocelink.com/startup-apply/

Plugins:
Elementor page builder

Theme:
RARA Business

Comment: "How do you search where in the CSS to edit for the Wordpress content to display full width" - it is not about WordPress but about CSS. A lot of people including myself use Chrome (or Firefox) developer tools for this. I personally use Chrome so I press Ctrl+Shift+J, select "Elements" section and then see what is wrong. The good tone here is to post the code. People don't like real websites for a lot of reasons, incl. security threat.

Comment: Do you want to show it like this? https://nimb.ws/mOMUrq

Comment: Have you chosen a theme that shows content in full width, rather than having to alter the css yourself.

Comment: @AHaworth I haven't, was going to try some editing myself

Comment: @m4n0 that is correct! how did you do it?

Comment: @terry Try the answer below. The same that I did.

Comment: @m4n0 ok tried, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not only here you need to change

```
.full-width #content .content-grid {
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but also take a look at this style

```
.elementor-section.elementor-section-boxed > 
.elementor-container {
   max-width: 1140px; // here you have a limitation
}
```

The above style is in two places so you need to change there.

Comment: How did you searched for the codes from the page source? Eg it didnt appear to be there?

.full-width #content .content-grid {
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: I run `developer tools` in chrome
and using the first icon you look for the right place in the code, 10 seconds later you modify the code in the console :)